# Read-only visualisation in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to show a visualisation in Spotfire but disable user interaction, especially the ability to click on data points and change existing markings?
I want to use such a vis as a 'read only' report where markings deliver certain info but need to block users from changing these markings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the user's ability to mark data on a visualization. For most visualization types this can be achieved by right-clicking the visualization then selecting properties -> data and setting the "marking" drop-down to "none". You'll need to do this on each visualization where you want to prohibit marking.

A more robust solution would be achieved by creating a new marking scheme for the instances where you need your pre-determined marking to "deliver certain info". Go to File->document properties-> markings. Here you can add new marking schemes (colors). These will populate the drop down menus in the data->markings section of each visualization. So for example perhaps you could have the default green marking available in some visualizations but add a new red marking and leverage it for the purposes you need.